# Qual è l'uso corretto dei tempi verbali in queste frasi?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

Ho scritto questa frase: "Mio padre, per primo, strinse amicizia con voi e l'ha protratta fino alla fine della vita". Ma è corretto l'uso del passato prossimo ("ha protratta") nella seconda frase se nella prima ho usato quello remoto ("strinse")?

Un dubbio simile mi è venuto per quest'altra: "Dopo che l'esercito penetrò in Asia, non mi allontanai mai dal comandante". Va bene "penetrò" o dovrei dire "fu penetrato"? Il verbo nella principale è corretto?

Answer (score 2):

Nella frase

> Mio padre, per primo, strinse amicizia con voi e l'ha protratta fino alla fine della vita

il passato remoto *strinse* indica un'azione sentita come lontana nel tempo e che non ha nessuna relazione con il presente; invece il passato prossimo *l'ha protratta* indica che l'azione è avvenuta fino a un momento molto recente e in certo senso si sente ancora come presente. Puoi scrivere anche

> Mio padre, per primo, strinse amicizia con voi e la protrasse fino alla fine della vita

ma il significato è diverso: il passato remoto *la protrasse* indica che quest'azione si sente come conclusa nel passato e la frase non vuole avere nessun riferimento al presente.

Secondo Maria Cristina Peccianti, *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* (Giunti Editori, 2013):

> Il trapassato remoto indica un'azione o uno stato del passato, anteriore ad un altro fatto passato. Ha ormai un uso raro e limitato alle proposizioni temporali. Esempi:
>
> - Solo quando il treno ***fu partito*** mi ricordai che non avevo convalidato il biglietto.
> - Appena ***ebbe visto*** la casa, decise di rimanere.

La tua frase ha una struttura molto simile a questi esempi riportati nel libro citato e anche a quest'altro esempio tratto da [questo articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/trapassato-remoto_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/)

> Dopo che le ragazze ***furono partite***, i genitori se ne tornarono a casa

o a quest'altro tratto da [Grammatica italiana.eu](http://www.grammaticaitaliana.eu/trapassato_remoto.html)

> Dopo che gli invitati ***furono andati*** via, andai a dormire.

Quindi, per indicare che l'azione di penetrare in Asia fatta dall'esercito è anteriore a quella di non allontanarsi dal comandante, siccome il verbo "penetrare" con uso intransitivo richiede l'ausiliare "essere", la frase dovrebbe essere

> Dopo che l'esercito *fu penetrato* in Asia, non mi allontanai mai dal comandante.

Anche in [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=_a7hAAAAMAAJ&q=%22fu+penetrato%22&dq=%22fu+penetrato%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dWTXVLXOE7fCsASvlYEo&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ) puoi trovare una frase simile alla tua:

> «Ma dopo di ciò, quando tutto l'esercito ***fu penetrato***, vinti dalle grandi masse di uomini si ritirarono nelle varie città, ciascuno a portare soccorso alla propria patria.»

Tuttavia, secondo l'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/indicativo-trapassato-remoto_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/) questo uso del trapassato remoto appartiene a un registro alto della lingua scritta. In un uso più comune il trapassato remoto può essere sostituito dal passato remoto, come appunto hai fatto tu nella frase che hai scritto:

> Dopo che l'esercito penetrò in Asia, non mi allontanai mai dal comandante.

Answer (score -1):

Andando per gradi: la prima frase "Mio padre, per primo, strinse amicizia con voi e l'ha protratta fino alla fine della vita". Guardando soltanto strettamente la grammatica: "l'ha protratta": Come qualcuno ha già risposto potrebbe essere corretta nel caso in cui la dipartita del padre in questione sia recente. Ma in linea di massima mi sentirei di dire che la forma corretta è il passato remoto, quindi "la protrasse".

Quindi la frase sarebbe: "Mio padre, per primo, strinse amicizia con voi e, la protrasse fino alla fine della sua vita."

Nota a margine: Il tono di questa frase è molto polemico, se questa è l'intenzione, allora ignora pure la prossima frase: Il verbo protrarre ha un'accezione di "Qualcosa che si continua a fare nel tempo controvoglia" (Dal latino: Pro + Traho, tirare avanti). Riferito ad un'amicizia, ovviamente assume un tono particolare. Un verbo più neutro o tendenzialmente positivo potrebbe essere Mantenere (e la mantenne).

Per quanto riguarda la seconda domanda, non sono tanto i tempi verbali, ad essere fuori posto, ma gli avverbi, anche se, come ho risposto per quanto riguarda la domanda precedente, la forma temporale corretta per indicare anteriorità, in questo caso è il trapassato remoto "fu penetrato":
"Dopo che" è entrata nell'uso comune per reggere una temporale con senso di anteriorità, ma le forme "Una volta che" e "Da quando" sono più corrette. Un'altra forma utilizzabile è spezzare il periodo in due reggenti: "L'esercito penetrò in Asia, dopodichè, ..." In questo ultimo caso l'unica forma corretta è il passato remoto.
L'avverbio mai invece è decisamente sbagliato. Mai indica qualcosa che non è mai (per l'appunto) accaduto nel tempo. Qui l'avverbio corretto è più, che indica qualcosa che prima era vera e ha smesso di esserlo.

"Una volta che l'esercito fu penetrato in Asia, non mi allontanai più dal comandante."

Comment: Protrarre può non essere il verbo migliore in questo caso, ma non ha affatto l'accezione di "Qualcosa che si continua a fare nel tempo controvoglia".

Comment: Per quanto riguarda un'amicizia si.

Comment: Ma non mi pare proprio. Esempi in letteratura a sostegno della tua teoria? Sui vocabolari questa presunta accezione è assente e cercando su Internet ho trovato molte amicizie "protratte" assolutamente non controvoglia.

Answer (score -2):

'Mio padre, per primo, strinse amicizia con voi e l'ha protratta fino alla fine della vita.'

Considerato che quel padre è morto, sarebbe preferibile '... e la protrasse fino ...', c'è più enfasi, epica e retorica così.

Giusto noto che il verbo 'protrarre', avendo generalmente una connotazione negativa, non sembra funzionare lì; è un po' come se il prolungarsi dell'amicizia fosse stato — per questo padre — una sorta di concessione o, comunque, qualcosa di non particolarmente desiderabile.

'Dopo che l'esercito penetrò in Asia, non mi allontanai mai dal comandante.'

Qui 'penetrò' funziona, ma la tua prospettazione di sostituirlo con 'fu penetrato' assolutamente no.

Se infatti dicessi 'Dopo che l'esercito *fu penetrato* in Asia, ...', staresti intendendo che l'esercito era già penetrato in Asia, ma lì, a sua volta, fu penetrato, p.e., dall'esercito nemico.

Sicché, semmai, dovresti prospettare un confronto con 'ebbe penetrato'(†), forma che, però, appare piuttosto arcaica.

(†) 'Dopo che l'esercito ebbe penetrato in Asia, non mi allontanai mai dal comandante.'

Comment: "La tua prospettazione di sostituirlo con 'fu penetrato' assolutamente no". Care to explain?

Comment: Al mio orecchio suona meglio *fu penetrato*, azione anteriore a quella di non allontanarsi dal comandante. Sembra che tu lo confonda con una forma passiva, ma l'uso è intransitivo, quindi non è possibile.