# Sull'uso attuale del trapassato remoto

Tags: word-usage, verbs, past-tense

Nel libro *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* di Maria Cristina Peccianti (Giunti Editori, 2013) ho letto queste spiegazioni in riferimento all'uso del trapassato remoto:

> «Il **trapassato remoto** è un tempo composto che si forma con il passato remoto dell'ausiliare (*essere* o *avere*) e il participio passato del verbo. Anch'esso indica un'azione o uno stato del passato, anteriore ad un altro fatto passato.»
>
> «Il trapassato remoto ha ormai un uso molto raro, e limitato alle proposizioni temporali.»

Ecco gli esempi di uso del trapassato remoto che appaiono in questo libro:

> - Solo quando il treno ***fu partito*** mi ricordai che non avevo convalidato il biglietto.
> - Appena ***ebbe visto*** la casa, decise di rimanere.

Il dubbio sull'uso del trapassato remoto mi ha assalito quando ho letto questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/4038/707). Non so se si tratti di una buona risposta poiché al momento presente non ha ricevuto nessun voto. Questo post propone la frase seguente:

> «Mio padre, per primo, ebbe stretto amicizia con voi e, la protrasse fino alla fine della sua vita.»

Quello che mi sembra strano è che il trapassato remoto "ebbe stretto" non venga usato in una proposizione temporale. Per questa ragione, vi chiedo: è l'uso del trapassato remoto in questa frase da considerarsi arcaico? Qual è lo stato dell'uso del trapassato remoto nell'italiano contemporaneo?

Comment: La frase con “mio padre etc.”, così come è, ha qualcosa che non va, come se chi la formulò avesse voluto fare sfoggio quasi eccessivo di ricercatezza grammaticale. Se anche ci fosse stata una proposizione temporale (“...dopo che ebbe stretto amicizia...”), il trapassato sarebbe suonato strano, perché si usa per lo più per eventi puntuali (come confermano gli esempi sulla partenza del treno e la visita della casa).

Comment: Uhm apparentemente ero in errore. Ho modificato la risposta.

Answer (score 3):

Il trapassato remoto non è frequente ed è adatto a un registro – come si suol dire – sorvegliato, ma non lo considererei desueto o qualcosa del genere. È l'unica forma corretta (se in linguistica vogliamo parlare di “correttezza”) in frasi come le prime due riportate da Charo. Le alternative (“solo quando il treno partì mi ricordai” etc.) avrebbero un senso diverso, di contemporaneità anziché di successione nel tempo; se proprio si vuole evitare il trapassato, si deve ricorrere a qualche perifrasi, magari senza usare un verbo (“solo dopo la partenza del treno...”).

Che il trapassato non sia trapassato (mi scuso per il gioco di parole) lo testimonia il solito Google Ngram Viewer: per “[fu andato](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fu%20andato&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfu%20andato%3B%2Cc0)” sembra che tra alti e bassi sia tuttora vitale; con altri verbi, si osserva un certo declino.

Per completezza, vedo che Serianni dice cose molto simili alla Peccianti sulla rarità (ed «è addirittura disusato nell'ausilire *essere* (*fui stato*) e nei passivi (*fui stato amato*)») e sull'attuale uso solo nelle proposizioni temporali.

Comment: Anche [questo articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/trapassato-remoto_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) afferma: «Il trapassato remoto appare solo in subordinate temporali che esprimono un’anteriorità immediata rispetto al passato remoto nella principale.»

Answer (score 1):

L'uso del trapassato remoto, anche  in campo letterario, è ormai raro. Come fa notare  Mari Cristina Peccianti, il trapassato remoto è molto raro nel linguaggio contemporaneo. La stessa frase sarebbe  comunemente scritta:

- Mio padre  per primo strinse  amicizia con voi e la protrasse fino alla fine della sua vita.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ebbe%20stretto%2Cstrinse&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cebbe%20stretto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrinse%3B%2Cc0): ebbe stretto - strinse

[USI](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/indicativo-trapassato-remoto_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/): (Treccanionline)

> - **Il trapassato remoto ha ormai un uso molto raro e limitato ai registri alti della lingua scritta.**
> - Nell’uso comune, molto spesso il trapassato remoto è sostituito dal ➔passato remoto o dal ➔trapassato prossimo. Esempi:
>
>   - Non appena finì di mangiare, se ne andò 
>       Dopo che mia sorella aveva sentito la notizia, è corsa a spifferarla in giro

(Non è possibile costruire la forma passiva del trapassato remoto dell’indicativo.)